# Remove last digit from string

Tags: awk, sed, scripting, cut

I have a file `test.txt`, below the content:

```
SCDE1
SF9
STR1D2
SREDF21
FRED
STER2R4
```

I want to remove only the last character if it's a digit, so the output should be as below:

```
SCDE
SF
STR1D
SREDF2
FRED
STER2R
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is not working?

Answer (score 3):

Does this match your criteria?

Input data:

```
cat user324294
SCDE1
SF9
STR1D2
SREDF21
FRED
STER2R4
```

And transformation:

```
sed 's/[0-9]$//' user324294 
SCDE
SF
STR1D
SREDF2
FRED
STER2R
```

Explanation of the regex: any digit followed by a line end gets replaced with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This removes the last character if it is a number.

```
sed 's|[0-9]$| |g' file
```

Output:

```
SCDE
SF
STR1D
SREDF2
FRED
STER2R
```

Comment: That trailing whitespace! 

Comment: `g` is useless here

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a regex (Regular Expression) to match your text.
The regex that match **one** number is `[0-9]`. The end of the line is `$`.
Both together:

```
 [0-9]$
```

Now, we can use `sed` to remove the text on each line:

```
 sed 's/[0-9]$//' test.txt
```

If you need to replace several digits, use a repetition modifier, probably * in this case. Not what you are asking but useful to know:

```
 sed 's/[0-9]*$//' test.txt
```